# Missing mp3 files on SD card

Tags: external-sd, files, mp3

I am trying to add mp3 files to my Toshiba Thrive trough an SD card. What I am doing is loading the SD card in my laptop and adding the files directly. I loaded around 6 GB to the (32GB) card. When accessing the SD card files trough the tablet it only shows half of the files. I've done this process a couple of times, also I reformatted the SD card but tablet only reads some of the files and some other folders that I created for other documents don't even appear when I load the card on the tablet. Any insights on this?

Comment: Are you sure the file formats are all .mp3s?

Answer (score 2):

if you use the tablet mount function to mount the sdcard to computer, and copy some files, sometimes it has problem, it need more times, and suggestion refresh in the folder when finish copy, when you fresh you can check the copy successful or not.

if you use the sdcard reader to mount to the computer, when finish copy, need **safe remove usb** to ensure the copy finish.